# Adding more templates into editor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have been using ckeditor 4 in my CMS and using the template feature to allow the user to add a collection of template styles they've agreed open in to the editor so they are able to create uniquely styled pages. I have it so they can see the different colours templates within the editor, which allows them to see what section there typing content into.

[image]

The problem i'm finding is that after its saved and i go back into the editor to add another template, it only adds it within a existing template and i am unable to click outside of it. The only way i have to get round it is to copy and paste a section from the source.

Is their a way to allow me to click or move the cursor outside the template so i can add another one underneath it and not in it?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your editor the [Magic Line](http://ckeditor.com/addon/magicline) plugin. It adds a "floating bar" that allows to place the cursor after elements like tables, divs, ...

Comment: Hi Alfonso, thanks for your reply. I thought it might be something with that but it seems to totally ignore my last div as the magic line doesnt get that far. Ill have a look at magicline docs to see if there is a config for it.

Comment: Thank you very much. it was partly due to the magic line and also the way ckeditor uses <p> tags. I added &nbsp; within them and my templates are now working fine and so is the magic line. What a legend you are. thanks again